# Injecting angular controller in jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller, jasmine

I have read through many examples in regards to injecting controllers into a jasmine unit test, however I keep getting "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined".

Here is my code:

main.spec.js:

```
'use strict'

describe("Testing Main Controller", function(){
    var scope, controller;
    var dummyFunction = function(){};
    var defaultDocument = {
        _id: "123456"
    };
    beforeEach(module('app.controllers'));
    beforeEach(module('app'));
    beforeEach(inject(function($rootScope, $controller) {
        scope = $rootScope.$new();
        controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            SearchService: dummyFunction,
            ResultsService: dummyFunction,
            FacetService: dummyFunction,
            EsDateService: dummyFunction,
            Likes: dummyFunction,
            Bookmarks: dummyFunction
        });
    }));
    describe("Likes", function(){
        it('shall give the user the ability to like a document that is currently being displayed.', function(){
            scope.updateLike([defaultDocument]);
            expect(defaultDocument.isLiked).toBe(true);
        });
        it('shall give the user the ability to remove a like from a document that is currently being displayed.', function(){
            defaultDocument.isLiked = true;
            scope.updateLike([defaultDocument]);
            expect(defaultDocument.isLiked).toBe(true);
        });
    });
});
```

main_controller.js:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('app.controllers')
    .controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, SearchService, ResultsService, FacetService, EsDateService, Likes, Bookmarks) {

});
```

app.js:

```
angular.module('app.services', ['ngResource', 'elasticjs.service']);
angular.module('app.controllers', [ 'app.services']);

var app = angular.module('app', [
    'ui.bootstrap',
    'elasticjs.service',
    'app.services',
    'app.controllers',
    'app.config',
    'facet.directives',
    'ngRoute']);
    app.config(['$routeProvider',
        function($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/', {
                    controller: 'SearchCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'views/search/search.html'
                })
                .when('/journal', {
                    controller: 'JournalCtrl',
                    templateUrl: 'views/journal/journal.html'
                })
                .otherwise({
                    redirectTo: '/'
                });
        }
    ]);
    app.config(['$locationProvider',
        function($locationProvider) {
            $locationProvider.hashPrefix("!");
        }
    ]);
```

When I attach MainCtrl to app rather than app.controllers it seems to find MainCtrl.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try this, inject `$controller` and instantiate controller in each `it`.

Comment: Like this? it('shal', function($controller){
            controller = $controller('MainCtrl', {
            $scope: scope,
            SearchService: dummyFunction,
            ResultsService: dummyFunction,
            FacetService: dummyFunction,
            EsDateService: dummyFunction,
            Likes: dummyFunction,
            Bookmarks: dummyFunction
        });
            scope.updateLike([defaultDocument]);
            expect(defaultDocument.isLiked).toBe(true);
        }); Returns with TypeError: undefined is not a function

Comment: You need to inject $controller, `it('...', inject(function($controller) { ... }))`.

Comment: I see, I end up with the same initial error. "Error: [ng:areq] http://errors.angularjs.org/undefined/ng/areq?p0=MainCtrl&p1=not%20a%20function%2C%20got%20undefined".  I think it has something to do with my modules.  If I attach MainCtrl to "app" rather than "app.controllers" it works

Comment: What is order of your `app.js` and `main_controller.js`? `app.js` should come before `main_controller.js`.

Comment: In the order in which they are pulled in the karma.config.js?  If so I am loading the app.js prior to the main_controller.js.

Comment: Weird... try removing `beforeEach(module('app'));` since you don't need that in the tests.

Comment: Yea I tried various ways of putting the modules in.  Just module('app'), just module('app.controllers'), and both.  Nothing seems to get it to work.  I am starting to think there is something inherently wrong with how I have this structured, but the application itself works so I really am unsure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to re-declare dependencies for app module, as app module injects `app.controllers`

```
beforeEach(module('app'));
```

Quick example how it can be solved - http://jsfiddle.net/PtXFb/